# Regex issue to enclose the string with span php

Tags: php, regex

```
foreach ($ignoreWords as $ignoreWord) {
    if (preg_match("/([^\w^\ ]|\<\w+\>|(\w+\'?))?(" . preg_quote($ignoreWord) . "(\'s)?)(\<\/\w+\>|[^\w^\ ])?/", $string)) {
        $replacement = '<span class="clsIgnoreWord">' . $ignoreWord . '</span>';
        $pattern = "/(\<br\/?\>|(\w+\'?))?(".preg_quote($ignoreWord).")(\<br\/?\>)?/";
        $result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
        $stringArray[$key] = $result;
    }
}
```

Here the pattern is regex which encloses the ignoreWord variable $ignoreWord value with the span in the paragraph named as $string.Suppose here the $ignoreword is Question then:

1. **Question**
2. **'Question'**
3. **"Question"**
4. **Question's**
5. **def'Question**
6. **`Question`**
7. **(Question)**
8. **[Question]**
9. **{Question}**
10. **Question`<br/>` (any tag can appear after Question)**
11. **`<br/>`Question (any tag can appear befor Question)**
12. **Question:**
13. **Question;**
14. **Question,**
15. **@Question (Here apart from @ it can be any special character)**

After finding all those "Question" i want to enclose them with this:
`<span class='clsIgnoreWord'>Question</span>`.Here only the enclosure should be applied around the "Question" word.It should not change the word or meaning apart from it...or remove any character around it.

Most of the cases that i want with the above code are satisfied but some of the cases have still problem that are mentioned below

- it replaces abc's with abcs,in this case span tag should only enclose the abc and the replacement should not be happen and the original text should remain as it is.
- if it finds abcdef then it applies replacement inside the word and the replacement applies to the abc part of the abcdef string ....if there is any character on either side of the abc,the enclosure should be not applied.
- It also replaces abc in the abc-def...this not need to happen.The enclosure should not be applied In this case also.

What changes should be applied to the above code so that above mentioned cases also satisfies?

Comment: Can you please provide list of possible input data and expected results? I don't really understand what should happen with `abc's`.

Comment: You say _it replaces abc's with abcs_, but your code doesn't do that. You should clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want

```
$pattern = "/\b(".$ignoreWord.")\b/i";
$replacement = '<span class="clsIgnoreWord">' . $ignoreWord . '</span>';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

[Example using your test data](https://regex101.com/r/rZ2qP4/1).

The key here is `\b`, [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Word boundary is zero-width match that occurs between "word character" and "non-word character" (including beginning and end of string, `^` and `$`). What counts as "word character" depends on current locale, but I don't think that punctuation ever does.

Comment: This is not detecting the "Question" string in the single "Question-Answer" word.This should not happen.....

Comment: @BhaveshTilvani Of course it does detect "Question" in "Question-Answer". See website I have linked to. If it does not detect that string in your code, then something else is going on. And how about providing expected results for examples you have given?

Comment: I know it is detecting...and your code is reflecting according to that too..but i does not want this case to be deteted....so can you update regex to just ignore for this case only....

Comment: @BhaveshTilvani I am going to ask this again and for the last time. Please edit your question to include two lists: "I have this" and "I want this". Give all examples you can think of. "Question-Answer" is not in your question right now and you can't expect people to figure it out without your help. Include these two lists and we can work the resolution from there.

Comment: Zalewski.The cases which i want are the 15 that are marked as bold......and below that i have mentioned the points which i does not want in my regex.......what i had was already in code and are mentioned as 15 bold points...what i want was from the existing regex was mentioned as the points below the 15 cases.....still some edit require..then suggestions are welcomed.....

Comment: Zalewski ....Can you suggest the correct regex....as i want this by today itself.........